# Add if statement to Airflow before running

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an Airflow DAG which runs fine, these are the task

```
T1 = deletes all files from GCS
T2 = Runs SQL query 1 and outputs to a table within BigQuery 
T3 = Runs SQL query 2 and outputs to a table within BigQuery
T4 = Runs SQL query 3 and places a copy of this output as csv into the GCS that was emptied in T1
T5= Copies and Appends the reference numbers from the file in T4 to a history table in BigQuery.
```

Now I'm trying to add in a check to see if it's the last Tuesday of the month;

- if it is, the codes prgress  onto T1>>T2>>T3 etc
- else it stops and runs none of the tasks.

I've tried with Bash but no luck

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a [sensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/sensors.html). A sensor will wait for something to happen and continue running the downstream tasks. For your use case, the best option would probably be to create a [python sensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/python/index.html) that checks for the condition.

Answer (score 0):

As Airflow scheduler supports [extended cron syntax through croniter lib](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html#cron-presets), you could establish a schedule using this approach.

In [Croniter Github](https://github.com/kiorky/croniter) there are a lot of examples, but one looks exactly what you´re looking for:

```py
[...]
croniter('0 0 * * 5#3,L5', base)  # 3rd and last Friday of the month
```

So, for your needs, would be something like this in your DAG:

```py
  ...
  "schedule": "0 0 * * 2L",
  ...
```